# I have some questions before installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

Hello i have waited for ubuntu 14.04 release so that i wouldnt have to upgrade later. My problem is that when i try ubuntu from a usb the mouse curser is flickering, It's very annoying. Also i have heard that you shouldn't install ubuntu if it doesn't work proparly when you try it. Should i go safe and wait to install ubuntu or try another ubuntu version like xubuntu or is this normal since the os is running from the usb?

Computer:

Asus K53SM

intel core i5 2.6GHz
Nvidia GT630m
4GB ram

Answer (score 1):

For cursor flickering go to **System Settings > Displays**.In the Displays window, you will see an **Unknown monitor**. Click it and disable it. Voila! Mouse flickering should be gone.

If everything else looks fine then you can proceed with installation of Ubuntu 14.04. Also looking at your system specs I really dont think there would be a problem.